# Laravel AJAX response

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to return array from laravel controller. Here is my code,

```
$find = array("id"=>1,"id"=>2,"id"=>3);
$result = array("data"=>$find);
return $result;
```

My result is :

```
 {
  "data":
      [
        {"id":1},
        {"id":2},
        {"id":3}
      ]
 }
```

The result is in JSON format.
But i want to get it in Array Format like :

```
{
      "data":
          [
            ["id":1],
            ["id":2],
            ["id":3]
          ]
}
```

Comment: You can parse the result using jQuery.parseJSON():   `$.parseJSON('{ "data":  [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}] }');`

Comment: Can show your whole code of controller and route of that controller Or The Method which you used for this code.  Then i Will help on this.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible as `["id":1]` is not a valid JSON.

You can always validate JSON [here](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I don't want it in JSON format. I simply want it in array format without using json_encode() function.

Comment: The first issue is that it will be hard to parse it, second is when given an array like `["id": 1, "id": 2]`, the value of the 'key' id of the array will be rewritten to 2. ( Here is an example: http://ideone.com/LZNh4R ).